# What are the options for returning a custom DTO with a specific status code using ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, servicestack

We're using ServiceStack to build a web API. I have a situation where I want to be able to return a response of 400 (BadRequest) from an API endpoint *with* some additional data indicating the specific cause(s) of the error.

The two ways I know about to return a specific status code are:

1. Throw an exception.
2. Return an instance of `HttpResult`.

I'd rather not return an instance of `HttpResult`. It would require me to make the method return type more generic (currently the return type is the specific response DTO), and there are other reasons (having to do with our use of ServiceStack) why that is problematic.

The situation with throwing an exception is weird. Based on the form of the response, ServiceStack is using the custom DTO even in the exception case (and the docs confirm this). And the `HttpError` exception class has a `Response` property which corresponds to the DTO used to issue the response, *but* setting the `Response` property to an instance of the custom DTO does not have the intended effect. It only affects the value of the `ResponseStatus` property on the response DTO. The other properties on the DTO are uninitialized as though ServiceStack generated a fresh instance of of the response DTO and used that instead (but set its `ResponseStatus` property from the provided DTO.

Is everything I've said actually correct? Is there another option for forming the response that doesn't have the drawbacks I've mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to decorate a Response with additional metadata, return the response in a `HttpResult` - that's the entire purpose of the class. There's no visible difference to the HTTP Response body of a Response DTO returned directly vs wrapped in a `HttpResult`.

Alternatively you can just modify the `base.Response` directly, see the docs on [Customizing HTTP Responses](http://docs.servicestack.net/customize-http-responses).

Throwing an Exception is only returning a HTTP Error Response. ServiceStack has implicit structured error handling where it captures the Error in a ResponseStatus which is extracted from any Response DTO.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @mythz. Do you think a future version of ServiceStack might allow you to specify the entire DTO in the exception case? Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see much if any value in including DTO properties in the output in their initial state.

Comment: @DanielPratt You'd need to write to the Response directly to change the behavior which you could do this in a Service or Response Filter. The [Error Handling is described in the docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#error-response-types), It returns populated ResponseStatus in order for predictable structured error handling to be supported in clients which passes through Exception filters to convert the C# Error into the appropriate HTTP Response Error.

Comment: Well, I'm not thrilled with the answer, but it _is_ an answer and a timely one at that, so thanks.